# How to call Makefile from another Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm getting some unexpected results calling one makefile from another.  I have two makefiles, one called `/path/to/project/makefile` and one called `/path/to/project/gtest-1.4.0/make/Makefile`.  I'm attempting to have the former call the latter.  In /path/to/project/makefile, I have

```
dev: $(OBJ_FILES)
  $(CPPC) $(LIBS) $(FLAGS_DEV) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(PROJECT)
  $(MAKE) -f ./gtest-1.4.0/make/Makefile

clean:
  rm -f ./*~ ./gmon.out ./core $(SRC_DIR)/*~ $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
  rm -f ../svn-commit.tmp~
  rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/$(PROJECT)
  make -f gtest-1.4.0/make/Makefile clean
```

And in `/path/to/project/gtest-1.4.0/make/Makefile` I have

```
all: $(TESTS)

clean:
  rm -f $(TESTS) gtest.a gtest_main.a *.o
```

Issuing the following:

```
cd /path/to/project
make
```

Outputs:

```
make -f ./gtest-1.4.0/make/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/path/to/project'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/path/to/project'
```

However, when I issue these commands:

```
cd /path/to/project
make clean
```

I see:

```
make -f gtest-1.4.0/make/Makefile clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/path/to/project'
rm -f  gtest.a gtest_main.a *.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/path/to/project'
```

I don't understand: In both cases, `/path/to/project/makefile` is telling me it's entering the current working directory.  In the first case, it doesn't think it has work to do (when it does) and in the second case, it's able to find the appropriate directive (when the output is telling me it's looking in the wrong directory) yet it tries to run the `rm` command in `/path/to/project`, instead of `/path/to/makefile/gtest-1.4.0/make/`.

Am I missing something fundamental to calling makefiles from one another?  Have I made an egregious conceptual mistake, or hit a common pitfall?  How do I effectively change directories and call a second makefile from within the first?  My understanding was that simply calling `make -f <name>` would be enough.

This is make/gmake 3.81 in bash.

Comment: I think, instead of `make -f gtest-1.4.0/make/Makefile clean` you better say `$(MAKE) -C gtest-1.4.0/make clean`. Why you haven't defined phony targets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494999/subdirectories-and-makefiles

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I'm not really too clear what you are asking, but using the `-f` command line option just specifies a file - it doesn't tell make to change directories. If you want to do the work in another directory, you need to `cd` to the directory:

```
clean:
    cd gtest-1.4.0 && $(MAKE) clean
```

Note that each line in `Makefile` runs in a separate shell, so there is no need to change the directory back.

Comment: Instead of manually `cd`'ing to the `gtest-1.4.0` dir, you should use the `-C` option of `make`.

Comment: Or at the very least, you should definitely use `&&` between the cd and make command.  Otherwise if the cd fails it will still run `make clean`... in the wrong directory!!  Also you should always ONLY use `$(MAKE)`, never the bareword `make`, when recursing.  So something like:  `cd gtest-1.4.0 && $(MAKE) clean`

Comment: @Tader: `-C` is not in [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html)

Comment: This question about gnu-make and `-C` is in the spec: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion

Answer (score 143):

Instead of the `-f` of `make` you might want to use the `-C <path>` option. This first changes the to the path '`<path>`', and then calles `make` there.

Example:

```
clean:
  rm -f ./*~ ./gmon.out ./core $(SRC_DIR)/*~ $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
  rm -f ../svn-commit.tmp~
  rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/$(PROJECT)
  $(MAKE) -C gtest-1.4.0/make clean
```

Comment: This way seems to the best. Come of the other replies which use `cd` cause the terminal to get into a infinite loop.

Comment: $(MAKE) -C gtest-1.4.0/make clean does not work for me. I think it should be $(MAKE) -C gtest-1.4.0 clean

Answer (score 61):

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion

```
 subsystem:
         cd subdir && $(MAKE)
```

or, equivalently, this :

```
 subsystem:
         $(MAKE) -C subdir
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the official docs.

Comment: The highest voted answer didn't work for me, but this one did. Thanks. Example:
`.PHONY: db
db:
 $(MAKE) -C db/ build start`

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that `$(TESTS)` is empty so your 1.4.0 makefile is effectively

```
all: 

clean:
  rm -f  gtest.a gtest_main.a *.o
```

Indeed, all has nothing to do.  and clean does exactly what it says `rm -f gtest.a ...`

Comment: $(TESTS) is defined with a `wildcard` and a `patsubst`, however these are returning empty from the main makefile, because the directory is not being effectively changed.  Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

in parent makefile put

```
clean:
    cd $(PWD)/path/to/project/gtest-1.4.0 && $(MAKE) clean
```

in order this to work, under **/path/to/project/gtest-1.4.0** must exist a **makefile** with `clean` option like follow

child makefile

```
clean:
    rm -f where_you_want
```