# Subdirectories and Makefiles

Tags: makefile

I think this is a question that has been asked many times but I cannot find the *right* way to do it.

I have the following structure:

```
project/
project/Makefile
project/code
project/code/*.cc
project/code/Makefile
```

When I am in the directory 'project/code' and call "make project_code" my code is compiling correctly.

I would like to do that when I am in 'project/', just calling "make project_code" as if I was in 'project/code'.

The makefile 'project/Makefile' will contain other rules (such as 'install') and some rules to compile as if I was in 'project/code'. And for that, I am requesting your help... Thanks.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The simplest way is to do:

```
CODE_DIR = code

.PHONY: project_code

project_code:
       $(MAKE) -C $(CODE_DIR)
```

The `.PHONY` rule means that `project_code` is not a file that needs to be built, and the `-C` flag indicates a change in directory (equivalent to running `cd code` before calling `make`).  You can use the same approach for calling other targets in the `code` Makefile.

For example:

```
clean:
       $(MAKE) -C $(CODE_DIR) clean
```

Comment: Thanks, it works !

One last thing: is $(MAKE) always defined ?

Comment: is $(MAKE) a reference to a variable you defined? Or is that a built in function that is always there?

Comment: It's built in to GNU Make, see the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the output of this call? @$(MAKE) doesn't work as expected.

Comment: How can this be done for multiple subdirectories? When I try appending another subdirectory target to PHONY, only the first target is ran.

Comment: btw, was just reading at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets that even clean actions should use .PHONY to avoid the rare case where a file named clean exists

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this rule in project/Makefile something like this (for GNU make):

```
.PHONY: project_code
project_code:
       cd code && make
```

Comment: This will *not work* as written, because by default in GNU make, each line of a rule body is executed in a different shell.  So, the cd will occur, but the shell that executed it will immediately exit; then 'make' will be executed separately.  In fact, I believe this will put make into an infinite recursion loop.  However, if you change you code to 'cd code && make', it will work as expected.

Comment: Edited after 4 years to match the suggestion

Comment: @EmanueleCipolla Thumb up after another four years to salute the spirit.

Comment: And here we are almost four years to the date, again which only proves that `make` is a timeless piece of software and proper `Makefile` writing should be a part of every basic computer skills course.