# Run make in each subdirectory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a directory (`root_dir`), that contains a number of sub-directories (`subdir1, subdir2, ...`).

I want to run the `make` in each directory in `root_dir`, using  a Makefile placed in it.
(Obviously supposed that each of `subdir...` has inside its own Makefile).

So there are essentially two questions:

1. How to get a list of directories in Makefile (automatically)?
2. How to run `make` for each of the directories inside a make file?

As I know in order to run `make` in a specific directory I need to do the following:

```
$(MAKE) -C subdir
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There are various problems with doing the sub-make inside a for loop in a single recipe.  The best way to do multiple subdirectories is like this:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

all: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS)
```

(Just to point out this is GNU make specific; you didn't mention any restrictions on the version of make you're using).

*ETA* Here's a version which supports multiple top-level targets.

```
TOPTARGETS := all clean

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: $(TOPTARGETS) $(SUBDIRS)
```

Comment: What if I want also the clean target ?

Comment: Why $(SUBDIRS) are in the .PHONY ? Is that because the directory modification date/time does not matter ? I have this question, because the directories are not fakes. .PHONY is supposed to be for fake targets.

Comment: `.PHONY` is for targets which you want to be built every time the makefile runs, regardless of whether it exists or not or is out of date.

Comment: @shuva You would most likely want to run the makefile in the subdirectory regardless whether the subdirectory has been changed because that makefile might have its own phony targets

Comment: @Claudio For clean target, see [this post](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2008-04/msg00052.html); though the example there says "untested", it works for me (removing the makefile name) .

Comment: Could you elaborate on "various problems?"

Comment: (1) can't use parallel builds across multiple subdirectories, (2) either won't exit on failure or else doesn't correctly support -k.  There may be others I've forgotten.

Comment: If you're a weirdo like me, running make on Windows, you might want to add some quotes: `"$(MAKE)" -C "$@" build`

Comment: To clarify, parallel builds are possible if there is no interdependence across the subdirectories' targets.

Comment: I am using the same layout and for whatever reason if sub-make fails, it does not break the make process,  it simply continuing to the next sub-directory?

Comment: If you have things set up as above that can't happen.  If it happens, there must be something different about your setup than what appears above.  You should open a new question providing a minimal reproducible example, the command you typed, the pertinent output you got, and describe what is wrong about it and what you wanted to see instead.

Answer (score 13):

Try this :

```
SUBDIRS = foo bar baz

subdirs:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$dir; \
    done
```

This may help you [link](http://lackof.org/taggart/hacking/make-example/)

Edit : you can also do :

The simplest way is to do:

```
CODE_DIR = code

.PHONY: project_code

project_code:
       $(MAKE) -C $(CODE_DIR)
```

The .PHONY rule means that project_code is not a file that needs to be
built, and the -C flag indicates a change in directory (equivalent to
running cd code before calling make). You can use the same approach
for calling other targets in the code Makefile.

For example:

```
clean:
   $(MAKE) -C $(CODE_DIR) clean
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494999/subdirectories-and-makefiles)

Comment: Actually I dont want to have a list of directories in the makefile

Answer (score 9):

This is another approach to [MadScientist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845120/9730945). `.PHONY` is a GNU-specific feature that can be used to force `make` into recursing into each subdirectory. However, some non-GNU versions of `make` do not support `.PHONY`, so an alternative is a [force target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html).

> 4.7 Rules without Recipes or Prerequisites
>
> If a rule has no prerequisites or recipe, and the target of the rule
>   is a nonexistent file, then make imagines this target to have been
>   updated whenever its rule is run. This implies that all targets
>   depending on this one will always have their recipe run.
>
> An example will illustrate this:
>
> ```
> clean: FORCE
>         rm $(objects)
> FORCE:
> ```
>
> Here the target ‘FORCE’ satisfies the special conditions, so the
>   target clean that depends on it is forced to run its recipe. There is
>   nothing special about the name ‘FORCE’, but that is one name commonly
>   used this way.
>
> As you can see, using ‘FORCE’ this way has the same results as using
>   ‘.PHONY: clean’.
>
> Using ‘.PHONY’ is more explicit and more efficient. However, other
>   versions of make do not support ‘.PHONY’; thus ‘FORCE’ appears in many
>   makefiles. See Phony Targets.

The following is a minimal example that recurses `make` into each subdirectory, each of which presumably contains a `Makefile`. If you simply run `make`, only the first subdirectory, which is non-deterministic, is processed. You may also run `make subdir1 subdir2 ...`.

```sh
# Register all subdirectories in the project's root directory.
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

# Recurse `make` into each subdirectory.
$(SUBDIRS): FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C $@

# A target without prerequisites and a recipe, and there is no file named `FORCE`.
# `make` will always run this and any other target that depends on it.
FORCE:
```

Here is another example with top-level phony targets: `all` and `clean`. Note that the `all` and `clean` targets, passed from command-line via `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`, are handled by each subdirectory's `all` and `clean` targets respectively.

```sh
# Register all subdirectories in the project's root directory.
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

# Top-level phony targets.
all clean: $(SUBDIRS) FORCE
# Similar to:
# .PHONY: all clean
# all clean: $(SUBDIRS)
# GNU's .PHONY target is more efficient in that it explicitly declares non-files.

# Recurse `make` into each subdirectory
# Pass along targets specified at command-line (if any).
$(SUBDIRS): FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

# Force targets.
FORCE:
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I had to use this on my Mac OS ( Ventura 13.5 ) to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

You can also define a function in the Makefile (also you of course need an additional makefile in each subdirectory). This is shell-dependent, but can be useful:

```
define FOREACH
    for DIR in packages/*; do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$DIR $(1); \
    done
endef

.PHONY: build
build:
    $(call FOREACH,build)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(call FOREACH,clean)

.PHONY: test
test:
    $(call FOREACH,test)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a library called **prorab** for GNU make which supports inclusion of standalone makefiles in subdirectories.

Some info on github: https://github.com/cppfw/prorab/blob/master/wiki/HomePage.adoc

Basically, with **prorab** invoking all makefiles in subdirectories looks like this:

```
include prorab.mk

$(eval $(prorab-include-subdirs))
```

Answer (score 3):

Only a small icing on the cake after MadScientist's answer in order to make all the individual targets in the sub-directories available from the top level (you will need to have the `SUBDIRS` variable defined in order to use the following snippet – you can use MadScientist's answer for that):

```
# Make all the individual targets in the sub-directories available from the top
# level; as in, for instance, `make foo/my_program` or `make bar/clean`
$(foreach __dir__,$(SUBDIRS),$(__dir__)/%):
        @$(MAKE) -C '$(@D)' '$(@F)'
```

---

With the code above you can run, for instance,

```
make foo/my_program
```

or

```
make bar/clean
```

Furthermore, by pasting the code above you can even use an individual target from a sub-directory as a prerequisite for a target in the top level. For example:

```
my_target: my_subdirectory/my_prerequisite
        'my_subdirectory/my_prerequisite' > 'my_target'
```

…With the example above, launching `make my_target` from the top level will first build the `my_subdirectory/my_prerequisite` program, then the latter will be run for building the `my_target` file.

Answer (score 2):

Since I was not aware of the MAKECMDGOALS variable and overlooked that MadScientist has its own implementation of multiple top-level targets, I wrote an alternative implementation. Maybe someone find it useful.

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

define submake
        for d in $(SUBDIRS);                  \
        do                                    \
                $(MAKE) $(1) --directory=$$d; \
        done
endef

all:
        $(call submake,$@)

install:
        $(call submake,$@)

.PHONY: all install $(SUBDIRS)
```

Comment: I don't know man, I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834582/run-make-in-each-subdirectory#comment110155627_17845120 is trying to convey is that for-loops are probelmatic with parallel builds.  See the answer betlow.

Answer (score 2):

In reference to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17845120/revisions

This is what I learned from that post.

Top Level Makefile

```
# set the default goal.
# I want the default to really just dump contents of dirs
# as a stub.  For instance, I don't want it to
# push code or
.DEFAULT_GOAL := deploy

TOPTARGETS := all clean

SUBDIRS := docs src 

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    echo "make arg is" $(MAKECMDGOALS)
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)




SUBCLEAN = $(addsuffix .clean,$(SUBDIRS))

clean: $(SUBCLEAN)

$(SUBCLEAN): %.clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $* clean

deploy:
    echo do deploy stub
```

The `src/` and `docs/` common to this `Makefile` directory, all have a corresponding `Makefile`.

Here is an example of the docs setup:

```
# set the default goal.
.DEFAULT_GOAL := list_docs



list_docs:
    ls -l


clean:
    echo "docs: make clean"
    -rm "*.backup"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this a little different than any of the answers because I didn't want to have to define each possible make target

```
SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/,%,$(wildcard */))

.PHONY: all $(MAKECMDGOALS) $(SUBDIRS)
$(MAKECMDGOALS) all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```