# GNU make - how to serialize calls to foreach $(MAKE)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have

`$(foreach ___project___, $(UNIT_TEST_STUBS),$(MAKE) -C ../../$(___project___) $(UT_CMD) || exit 1;)`

I want `make` to be parallel INSIDE each submake but I don't want the submakes to be executed in parallel.

How do I do this?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provide a complete rule, at the very least.  However, assuming what you've quoted here is the contents of a recipe, this will behave the way you want: each sub-make will be invoked serially, and within each sub-make the targets will be built in parallel.

Comment: @MadScientist then how would it be written if I wanted the submakes to be executed in parallel?

Comment: You can't do that from a single target/recipe.  You'll have to write one target per sub-make, so make can parallelize them properly.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834582/run-make-in-each-subdirectory/17845120#17845120

Comment: The snippet looks like a part of a recipe, and its expansion is `$(MAKE) -C ../../foo/ ut-cmd || exit 1; $(MAKE) -C ../../bar/ ut-cmd || exit 1; etc`.  So, the submakes will be executed serially by the same shell instance.  Just add `-j<whatever>` after `$(MAKE)` and you'll be all set.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MichaelLivshin I assumed that if you had `$(MAKE) -C A\ all\n $(MAKE) -C B\ all` the two makefiles would be executed in parallel; is that incorrect?

Comment: @Adrian yes, an individual recipe always runs serially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Michael Livshin points out, you already seem to have answered your own question.
Might be neater to rely on *make* rather than shell syntax to tie a load of commands together though.
Basically you want *make* to see something like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    ${MAKE} -C ../../foo/ -j9 ut-cmd
    ${MAKE} -C ../../bar/ -j9 ut-cmd
    ${MAKE} -C ../../bum/ -j9 ut-cmd
```

Auto generation from a list is fairly straight-forward.

```
submakes := foo bar bum

define generate-submake
  ${MAKE} -C ../../$1/ ut-cmd

endef

.PHONY: all
all: ; $(foreach _,${submakes},$(call generate-submake,$1))
```

Note the blank line in the definition of `generate-submake`. It's important.
Run this with `make -j9`.

If you really want everything in this makefile to run serially (but the sub-makes to be parallel), then just introduce a `.NOTPARALLEL` target.

```
.NOTPARALLEL:
```