# Recursive Makefile for make build

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile, gnu-make

I want to build a very large project with only one Makefile calling multiples Makefiles.

The main Make is in the root directory and each part of my project has its own Makefile.

That's what I made:

```
SUBDIRS = dir/dir_1/dir_11 dir/dir2/dir22 dir/dir3/dir33

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@
```

I've read :

http://lackof.org/taggart/hacking/make-example/

and

[Run make in each subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834582/run-make-in-each-subdirectory)

to find help but the thing is I want to "make build" and then "make lambda_update" for each dir.

I tried:

```
SUBDIRS = dir/dir_1/dir_11 dir/dir2/dir22 dir/dir3/dir33

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

make:   make build; make lambda_update

$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Comment: why recursive? I think you can achieve what you want with non-recursive

Comment: Do you have any solution ? @igagis

Comment: because it's to run a python script

Comment: I have a library for making non-recursive makefiles, you can read about it here: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md It also allows having separate makefiles for each subproject and a root makefile which calls each of those subproject makefiles.

Comment: But, reading your question, I think if you want to run `build` target and then `lambda_update` target, then the right way to do it is to just invoke make twice: `make build && make lambda_update`, as it seems like `build` and `lambda_update` are not tied with dependency rules

Comment: thanks @igagis for your answer, I'm not sure to understand, can you please show me an example of your method ?

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: There are errors:
 | => make /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C dir/dir1/dir11 build lambda_update make: *** dir/dir2/dir22: No such file or directory. Stop. make: *** [dir/dir3/dir33] Error 2

Comment: so, are you sure that those directories exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the targets you want to make in each sub-make to the sub-make command,
in the order you want to make them, e.g.

```
SUBDIRS = a b c

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ build lambda_update
```

Comment: thank you @Mike for your answer. Unfortunately I've this error message:
| => make
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C dir/dir1/dir11 build lambda_update
make: *** dir/dir2/dir22: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [dir/dir3/dir33] Error 2

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn Naturally, the directories in `SUBDIRS` have got to exist. If you want the `make` to create the directories it needs, that's a problem not apparent in your question.

Comment: of course it exists! I can do cd dir/dir1/dir11 then make it works.