# Makefile: how do I get the same behaiour as $@ when using a variable directly?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using similar code to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845120/1375972 which includes:

```
TOPTARGETS := zip test clean

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

This runs whichever make command is passed (from TOPTARGETS) on every subdirectory, which is what I want.

However I want to have a target `deploy` which has this same behaviour only when an environment variable is set. Here's what I've tried:

```
deploy:
ifdef GITLAB_CI
    @echo "GITLAB_CI variable is defined, running deploy on all subdirectories"
    $(MAKE) -C $(SUBDIRS) $(MAKECMDGOALS)

else
    @echo "snip"
endif
```

Notice the `$(MAKE)` line is the same as the `$(SUBDIRS)` one, just with the `$@` replaced with `$(SUBDIRS)` directly.

So the logic is when it runs in my CI it'll run the deploy recursively on all subdirectories, but when it's run locally it doesn't. The problem is that the `$(SUBDIRS)` in deploy doesn't behave as expected. When I run `make deploy` in a directory with 2 subdirectories:

```
> make deploy
GITLAB_CI variable is defined, running deploy on all subdirectories
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C subdir1/. subdir2/. deploy
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `subdir2/.'.  Stop.
make: *** [deploy] Error 2
```

Compared to `make clean` (one of my `TOPTARGETS`):

```
> make clean
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C subdir1/. clean
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C subdir2/. clean
```

So when the `TOPTARGETS` are used, the `$@` seems to unroll `$(SUBDIRS)` in a different way to when I write the same line myself with `$@` substituted to `$(SUBDIRS)`. Is there any way to get that behaviour myself in the `deploy` line? Or do I need to write my own for loop over `$(SUBDIRS)` inside that target?

Comment: What make tells you is that `make -C subdir1/. subdir2/. deploy` does not what you think: it descends into `subdir1/.` and tries to build the `subdir2/.` and `deploy` targets. As you do not have a `subdir2/.` target, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep what works and add a minimal `deploy` rule:

```
TOPTARGETS := zip test clean

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

ifdef GITLAB_CI
deploy: $(SUBDIRS)
else
deploy:
    @echo "snip"
endif
```

Or, maybe even simpler:

```
TOPTARGETS := zip test clean
ifdef GITLAB_CI
TOPTARGETS += deploy
else
deploy:
    @echo "snip"
endif

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thankyou! I was completely missing that the ifdef could be outside the targets. Using the second solution, it's really nice and much clearer than what I was trying to do.