# checking subfolders recursively for additional make files

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project. If it contains a `Makefile` in every level of each sub directories and there is a top most directory `Makefile`. Then how to make makefiles compile all the C files and output one resulted .o file at the root. How is it possible?

Comment: `output one resulted .o file at the root`  is obscure, each compiled file will produce an associated object (except if you directly produce the executable), if you want an alone object file you need to compile an alone source file. What link with *makefile* ? to do by hand or through *make* changes nothing about the compilation(s). Are you sure you speak about object (.o) rather than executable or lib ?

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834582/run-make-in-each-subdirectory?rq=1). It can probably help

Comment: If it's possible to produce a single `.o` file, probably you don't need more than one Makefile anyway.

Comment: @tripleee why kernel source has too many makefiles in everyfolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GNU make under GNU/Linux (or any UNIX-like OS with the `find` utility), have no spaces in your directory names and all your makefiles are named `Makefile`, the following could be a starting point. Add it to your top makefile and type `make all` to build all subdirectories:

```
SUBDIRS := $(dir $(shell find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'))

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS) all

all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Explanations:

`find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'` is a shell command that finds all files (`-type f`) named `Makefile` (`-name 'Makefile'`) in any subdirectory (`-mindepth 2`) of the current directory.

`$(shell CMD)` is the make function that passes the shell command `CMD` to the shell and returns the result.

`$(dir LIST)` returns the directory part of all paths of `LIST`.

`SUBDIRS := $(dir ...)` assigns all this to the make variable `SUBDIRS` (replace `SUBDIRS` by any name you want, it's just a name). So, if you have two subdirectories named `foo` and `bar/baz`, and if they contain a file named `Makefile`, `find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'` returns `foo/Makefile bar/baz/Makefile`, and `SUBDIRS := $(dir $(shell find . ...))` assigns `foo bar/baz` to the make variable `SUBDIRS`.

`.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS) all` declares that any name in the value of make variable `SUBDIRS`, plus `all`, are *phony* targets: that is, they are not real file names (even if files or directories with these names actually exist), and make, when asked to, shall rebuild them even if they already exist and are up to date with respect to their prerequisites.

`all: $(SUBDIRS)` tells make that the `all` target depends on all names in the value of make variable `SUBDIRS`; in order to make `all` make shall first make all names in the value of make variable `SUBDIRS`.

Finally:

```
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

is a make rule that explains how to make any name in the value of make variable `SUBDIRS`. The recipe (`$(MAKE) -C $@`) simply consists in invoking make again (`$(MAKE)`) but in the `$@` directory (`-C $@`). The reason why you must use `$(MAKE)` instead of just `make` can be found in the GNU make documentation. `$@` is one of the many make automatic variables. In recipes it expands as the current target. So, if the `SUBDIRS` make variable has value `foo bar/baz`, this rule is the same as the two separate rules:

```
foo:
    $(MAKE) -C foo

bar/baz:
    $(MAKE) -C bar/baz
```

Comment: Can u please explain what is `SUBDIRS := $(dir $(shell find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'))`. Is SUBDIRS is a make construct or environment variable and what is .PHONY and why u used $(MAKE) -C $@. I think -C is to change directory before reading makefile but what is `$@`?

Comment: @Alex SUBDIRS is a make variable.  `shell` instructs make to invoke `find` with the shell to produce a list of names and `dir` strips the trailing path component.  `.PHONY` tells make that neither `SUBDIRS` nor `all` are real targets.  You use $(MAKE) -C to re-invoke the proper MAKE in each directory listed in SUBDIRS.  `$@` is the name of whichever target caused the recipe to be run.