# Subdirectories and Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I am struggling with a C project having multiple subdirectories where the `.o` files should reside in a subdirectory "obj/". Like this:

```
/hzg/src/
/hzg/src/adaemon
/hzg/src/adaemon/obj
/hzg/src/bdaemon
/hzg/src/bdaemon/obj
/hzg/src/notrelateddir
```

C files are in `*daemon/`, matching `.o` files in `*daemon/obj`.
A main Makefile should reside in `/hzg/src` and there should be a Makefile in every `/hzg/src/*daemon`

I have defined my `$(SOURCES)` and derived the `$(OBJECTS)` with `$(subst...)`.

What I am struggling with is to get the prerequisites in a rule properly defined...

Here's what I have so far:

**(Sub-)Makefile in adaemon:**

```
[...]
SOURCES         =       $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS         =       $(patsubst %.c, obj/%.o, $(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS):  obj/%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CLFAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This works like a charm. What I am struggling with is the "master" Makefile. How can I tell make to take the `.o` from the `obj/` directory and search for the matching `.c` files?

**Makefile**

```
[...]
SUBDIRS         :=      common:hzgd:masterd:mqttd:

SOURCES         =       $(wildcard $(subst :,/*.c , $(SUBDIRS)))
OBJECTS         =       $(subst /,/obj/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES)))

BIN             =       hzgmasterd 

all             :       $(BIN)

$(BIN)          :       $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -rdynamic -o $(BIN) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
        @echo "Server done."

$(OBJECTS)      :       obj/%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Oh, I would not mind using the "make -C" command but in this case it should only descend into the directory when an `.o` file needs to be recompiled.

Comment: I recommend to change the title to something less like "Please close me, I am a duplicate." You might have more success with attracting users who actually know help. (In contrast to me, admittedly....)

Comment: _This works like a charm_: no this does not work at all. Try `$(OBJECTS): obj/%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)` and `$(CC) $(CLFAGS) -c $< -o $@` in your sub-makefiles.

Comment: Why do you need sub-makefiles if you build the whole project from a top Makefile?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: Because I want to be able to simply type "make" in the directory I am currently working.... no need to check other directories in this case.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: You are right, my posted sub-Makefile did not work. I have fixed it to the version working fine. Now it creates the .o files in obj/ as expected.
I need to know how to configure the "master-Makefile" now to reflect tje obj/ directory properly.

Comment: This is a question about how to make your very special and narrow organization of a C project work. As such it is a bad question for SO. May better to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run make in each subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834582/run-make-in-each-subdirectory)

Comment: _it should only descent into the directory when an `.o` file needs to be recompiled_ is the wrong idea.  It's not possible for the parent makefile to know when `.o` needs to be recompiled: that's what the sub-make is for.  If the parent makefile could determine that then you wouldn't need the sub-makes at all.  The parent should be invoking the sub-makes and letting them figure out whether anything needs to be done.

Comment: @MadScientist Well, if I do as you suggest the binary file will be linked every time no matter if any of the .o files has been updated.
Can I prevent this somehow?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet This helps a little bit but in the end I am what I commented above:
By creating a .PHONY rule for the $(SUBDIRS) it will always link no matter if any .o has changed or not....

Comment: The binary file should depend on the .o files.  It should definitely not depend (directly) on some PHONY subdirectory target; that will indeed rebuild it every time.  If the .o files have been updated then the binary will be rebuilt; if not, not.  The usual way this is done to make it simpler is that each subdirectory actually creates a static library out of all the .o files, then the executable lists those static libraries (one per subdirectory) rather than trying to list all the individual .o files.

Comment: @MadScientist Can you give me an example? Currently I have a single binary as a result- will this be different with library builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to structure your top-level makefile:

```
SUBDIRS := common hzgd masterd mqttd

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c ,$(SUBDIRS)))
OBJECTS := $(filter %.o,$(foreach D,$(SUBDIRS),$(patsubst $D/%.c,$D/obj/%.c,$(SOURCES))))

BIN      =  hzgmasterd 

all : $(BIN)

$(BIN) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -rdynamic -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
        @echo "Server done."

$(OBJECTS): $(SUBDIRS) ;

$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
```

I didn't actually try this but I think it will work.  By adding the semicolon these are actual rules and make will check the timestamps on the targets.

If you wanted to create a library in each subdirectory you'd define a rule that did that, probably naming the library after the directory it was in, that listed all the objects as prerequisites, then in this makefile you'd list one library per subdirectory as the prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @MadScientist.
Some minor glitches and types (ie foreach did not work) and I have a working solutions now.

**"Master"-Makefile:**

```
SUBDIRS     :=  common hzgd masterd mqttd
CSUBDIRS    :=  client

CFLAGS      =   -Wall
LIBS        :=  -lconfig -lcurl -ljson-c -lm -lmodbus -lmosquitto -lownet -lpthread -lsystemd -lical

SOURCES     :=  $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c ,$(SUBDIRS)))
OBJECTS     :=  $(subst /,/obj/,$(subst .c,.o,$(SOURCES)))
HEADERS     :=  $(wildcard *h)

CSOURCES    :=  $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c ,$(CSUBDIRS)))
COBJECTS    :=  $(subst /,/obj/,$(subst .c,.o,$(CSOURCES)))
CHEADERS    :=  $(wildcard client/*h)

BIN         :=  hzgmasterd
CBIN        :=  client/hzgclnt

all     :   $(BIN) $(CBIN)
server      :   $(BIN)
client      :   $(CBIN)

#====================== Master ============================
$(BIN)      :   $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -rdynamic -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    @echo "Server done."

$(OBJECTS)  :   $(SUBDIRS) ;

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS)  :
    $(MAKE) -C $@


#====================== Client ============================
.PHONY: $(CBIN)
$(CBIN)     :   $(CSUBDIRS)/
    $(MAKE) -C $<


#====================== Aufräumen ============================
.PHONY      :   clean
clean       :
    rm -f $(BIN) $(OBJECTS) $(COBJECTS)
```

**"Sub"-Makefiles:**

```
[...]
SOURCES     =   $(wildcard *.c)
HEADERS     =   $(wildcard ../*h)
OBJECTS     =   $(patsubst %.c, obj/%.o, $(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJECTS)
#==================================================
$(OBJECTS):  obj/%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CLFAGS) -c $< -o $@

#====================== Aufräumen ============================
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o obj/*.o
```

A minor glitch is now `make` descends into every subdirectory and executes another make process to decide if the target is up to date.
I understand this is by design even though it will cause additional steps.... however, it is working now even though I do not understand everything in the Makefile you posted.

Thanks a lot!
/Christian

Comment: I fixed the foreach problem, my bad.  If you don't want make to descend into every subdirectory, then you need to write your makefile as non-recursive (that is, put the rules for building the code into the top-level makefile rather than sub-makefiles).  Wanting to have a recursive makefile setup that doesn't descent into every subdirectory doesn't make sense.