# Is it possible to get make to autocomplete targets created with 'addsuffix' or 'addprefix'?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU Make of course.
I have the following setup:

```
Makefile

subdir1
--- Makefile
--- source1.c
--- binary1

subdir2
--- Makefile
--- source2.c
--- binary2
```

Both makefiles in the subdirs have a run target, which executes the binary generated by itself.
The root makefile contains the `all` target, which runs `make -C subir1 && make -C subdir2`:

```
SUBDIRS = subdir1 subdir2

all:
    @for DIR in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$DIR; \
    done

clean:
    @for DIR in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$DIR clean; \
    done

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

The bottom bit lets me execute `make all` for a single subdir.
I want a similar target for `make run`, generated by `$(SUBDIRS)`.
I tried

```
run-$(SUBDIRS):
   make -C $(subst run-,,$@) run
```

but the target expands to `run-subdir1 subdir2`, and doesn't add the prefix to the second item in `$(SUBDIRS)`

If i add a new var `RUN_TARGETS = $(addprefix run-, $(SUBDIRS)`, it works, but make doesn't recognize the targets for utocompletion. Is there any option to let make know that is has to expand RUN_TARGETS or any other method to prefix a list of item?

#### EDIT

The issue for me is my shell, zsh, and not make itself. Bash completion gets it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html):

```
run-%:
        $(MAKE) -C $* run
```

or if you prefer to be more explicit, a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html):

```
$(addprefix run-,$(SUBDIRS)): run-%:
        $(MAKE) -C $* run
```

Comment: You might also be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17834698/939557

Comment: Okay i've just tested it, but i get the same results i get with ```addprefix```: make runs but it doesn't suggest the target in the terminal :(

Comment: Autocompletion has nothing to do with make.  Make doesn't provide autocompletion: your shell setup has configured it somehow; since you've given no information about what distro you use, what shell you use, or how that is configured there's not much we can say for sure.  However, most likely it will only autocomplete on explicit targets.  I made a mistake in the static pattern rule example I gave; I fixed it above.  Using that should allow autocompletion to work, if it's written the "right" way.

Comment: My terminal completed the default all-target aswell as the contents of the $(SUBDIRS)-list, so i thought every other $(...) would be expanded by the completion system

Comment: I use zsh with compinit, i just checked bash with bash-completion, and it correctly completes all targets. So its a problem of the zsh completion, thank you!

Comment: Maybe whatever implementation of completion compinit (whatever that is) uses, only understands simple explicit rules and doesn't understand static pattern rules.  You should report this issue to the people who manage that completion facility in zsh.  I believe that the bash version invokes `make -p` and looks at the output.