# Makefile Tools activation in projects where makefile is not in root

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

I have a project where there is a `Makefile` in a sub-directory and I would like to use the VS Code Makefile Tools extension to configure builds.  This works fine when I open VS Code in the sub-directory where the `Makefile` resides.  However when I open VS Code in the parent directory I cannot activate the Makefile Tools extension.  I have tried following the instructions in the user documentation (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) but this does not seem to have any effect for me.  My settings are shown in the attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for this issue is to put a `makefile` in the root VS Code directory.  E.g., something like,

```
SUBDIRS := path/to/project1 project2

all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS)
```

Credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834582/run-make-in-each-subdirectory) for explaining how to nest Makefiles across sub-directories.