# compile a file in a submodule

Tags: git, makefile, git-submodules

A have a [repository](https://github.com/paul-green-stone/linked-list-ADT) which I want to make to be dependent on another repository (submodule). The submodule has a makefile which has a rule to compile a file to be an object one (the one with *.o* extension).

There is a folder structure:

- guard (*this is a submodule*)

  - .gitignore
  - guard.c
  - guard.h
  - makefile
  - README.md
  - guard.o (*after I **make** in /path/to/this/guard*)
- temp

  - list.o
  - main.o
- .gitignore
- .gitsubmodules
- data.h
- list.c
- list.h
- main.c
- makefile
- README.md

Here goes the content of makefile:

```
cc = gcc
objs = temp/main.o temp/list.o guard/guard.o
dirs = temp
CFLAGS = -O1

main: $(objs) 
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) -o a.out $(objs)

temp/main.o: main.c
    $(cc) -c -g -o temp/main.o main.c

temp/list.o: list.h list.c
    $(cc) -c -g -o temp/list.o list.c

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf temp ./*.o a.out 

$(shell mkdir -p $(dirs))
```

As you can see, in the first place I compile *guard* and then link an object file to my main program. This means I need to go to my *guard* folder, `make` it, then go back and `make` again the main module. I believe there must be a better way to do it or `make` it.

**What is an appropriate way to compile a program which is based on submodules?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you taken a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834582/run-make-in-each-subdirectory ?

Comment: This is just a case of using `make` on subdirectories. The fact that they're git submodules is inconsequential.