# How to set in a Makefile the folder in which files are created?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have my project organized such that all code-files are found in a subdirectory `code/`. I have two Makefiles, one in the main directory and one in the `code/` subdirectory.

The Makefile in the main directory contains (props to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494999/subdirectories-and-makefiles)):

```
# .PHONY rule means that project_code is not a file that needs to be built
.PHONY: project_code

project_code:
    $(MAKE) -C $(CODE_DIR)

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(CODE_DIR) clean

all: exe
```

The Makefile in the `code/` subdirectory contains something like:

```
exe: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -fopenmp -lpng

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

When I am now running `make` from the main directory, the `exe` file is created in the `code/` subdirectory, but I would like to have it in the main directory. My question: How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reffer this example:

```
#Name of outpu binary (exe) file;
PROGRAM_NAME := prog

# project dirs
export SRC_DIRS     := ./src1 ./src2
export INCLUDE_DIRS := ./include

#list of source files (with whitespace between them)
SRC_FILES := $(foreach dirname, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dirname)/*.c))

#Object files
OBJ_FILES := $(foreach filename, $(SRC_FILES), $(filename:.c=.o))

# Include flags
LOCAL_INCLUDES=$(foreach dirs, $(INCLUDE_DIRS), -I$(dirs))


# list of lib-flags for compiler. For example for math.h use    -lm
#LIB_FLAGS=-lm
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall $(LIB_FLAGS) $(LOCAL_INCLUDES)

#build executable file
$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OBJ_FILES)
        @echo "Build executable"
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# compile all object file
%.o: %.c
        @echo "Compile $(notdir $<)"
        @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#clean all
clean:
        @rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(PROGRAM_NAME)
```

It has only 1 Makefile. It takes sources from listed directories, create objects in same directories and then link to binary in current (top) dir

Comment: I do not understand `export...` in the beginning and why you are using `@$(CC)` instead of just `$(CC)` ....?  But you definitely helped me, that was the inspiration I needed!

Comment: The `export` is usually used in big build systems where one make is called from other Makefile. `export` makes variable to be available in all nested make calls. The `@` before command in the target turns of 'echo' of the command (by default make prints command before execute, and the `@` turn this print off)