# Calling other makefile from make

Tags: makefile, mingw

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206128/how-to-call-makefile-from-another-makefile) question and am somehow still unable to get `make` to properly call another `Makefile`. Here is my `Makefile`:

```
base:
    cd Base && $(MAKE)
```

`Base` is a sub-directory of my current directory where there is a different `Makefile` used to compile the files in said folder. However, when I call `make`, I simply get `nothing to be done for base`, whereas when I do `cd Base && make` from the command-line, I get expected behavior (i.e., compilation occurs). In case it is something wrong with the `Makefile` in `Base`, here is a copy of that as well:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -c
LINK=g++
LFLAGS=-O3

SRC=main.cpp
OBJ=..\lib\main.o
EXE=..\bin\test.exe

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ) $(SRC)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE)

..\lib\main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Use `make -C dir` to call make on another directory.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham: That worked perfectly. What does the `.PHONY` do?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets

Comment: See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

Comment: If you had tried replacing `cd Base && $(MAKE)` with `echo hello`, you would have noticed that this problem has nothing to do with Make calling Make.

Comment: Just to clarify: if a target exists and has no prerequisites (or no prerequisites which are newer), then make won't build the target.  It doesn't matter to make if the "target" is a file or, as in your case, a directory: only that it exists and it's older than all its prerequisites (if any).  That's why declaring it to be `.PHONY` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what $(MAKE) amounts to (I'm assuming just 'make'), but I have my makefiles setup in a cascading manner where one calls another in order to cover all subdirectories.

Each makefile has some common targets like 'all' and 'clean'.
Then my makefiles which are just delegating to subdirs look something like this:

```
.PHONY : all
all:
    cd SubDir1 && make $@
    cd SubDir2 && make $@
    ...

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    cd SubDir1 && make $@
    cd SubDir2 && make $@
    ...
```

$@ is an [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) which will be substituted for the target ('all' or 'clean' in the example above).

This allows you to run 'make', 'make clean', 'make all', or even 'make clean all' from the top-level dir and it will recurse through the subdirs specified in the makefiles for the appropriate target.  So if you run 'make clean' at the top, all directories in the makefile's list will be called with 'make clean'.

You can still use this technique even if you don't have common targets.  Simply change the automatic variable $@ with the appropriate target for each directory's makefile.