# How to improve my makefile in C to move object files and compile even if there are errors?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

I created the following `makefile`:

```
#COMPILER
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I./include/ -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -Wall
CORFLAGS=-I./include/ -c -ansi -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -g
COFLAGS=-I./include/ -Wall -Werror -fpic -c
CSOFLAGS=-shared
#vpath
vpath %.h ./include/
vpath %.c ./test/
vpath %.c ./source/
vpath %.o ./obj/
#PATH
SOURCE=./source/
OUT=-o ./obj/$@
TEST=./test/
OBJPATH=./obj/
#LISTS
CFILESWP=$(wildcard ./source/*.c)
TFILESWP=$(wildcard ./test/*.c)
CFILES=$(notdir $(CFILESWP))
TFILES=$(notdir $(TFILESWP))
TOFILES=$(TFILES:.c=.o)
OFILES=$(CFILES:.c=.o)
OFILESWP=$(addprefix ./obj/,$(OFILES))
NAMES=$(TOFILES:_test.o=)
HFILES=$(CFILES:.c=.h)
    
    
.PHONY: clean debug release all

debug: CSOFLAGS+=-g
debug: libds.so

release: CSOFLAGS+=-O2
release: libds.so

test: $(NAMES)
        
all: libds.so $(NAMES)

%: %_test.c libds.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -lds -g
    
#SHARED LIBRARY
libds.so: $(OFILES)
    $(CC) $(CSOFLAGS) -o libds.so $(OFILES)
    
#OBJFILES
%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(COFLAGS) -o $@ $< -g

#CLEAN
clean:
    rm -f *.o $(OBJPATH)*.o
    rm -f $(NAMES) libds.so
```

My make file creates a `shared library` which called `libds.so` on `make` command and creates compiled executables on `make test` command.

it takes source files called `TARGET.c` from `/source/` directory a.k.a `stack.c, queue.c, cbuffer.c` and compiles them togeher with their test files from `/test/` directory aka `stack_test.c, queue_test.c, TARGET_NAME_test.c`.

All the `.h` files are located in the `/include/` directory.

and there is also a `/obj` directory which should contains all the `object files` which created after running the `makefile`.

How can I make this `makefile` better?
How can I move all `.o` files to `/obj` directory after each run of `make`?
Is it possible to create each "project" without the need to compile ALL the targets?

I mean, can I write `make`, which will create the shared library, and then write `create stack` and it'll create only executable of `stack` which compiles `/source/stack.c, test/stack_test, include/stack.h` and all other associated `.h files` which appear to be inside the code of the source files.

Can I somehow force the `makefile` to run and compile only the projects that can be compiled and not to stop the `"making"`, the compilation of the files just because several projets that have syntax errors inside of them or some other errors?

For example:
If I have the following projects: `stack.c, queue.c, cbuffer.c`
and `cbuffer` cannot be compiled because something is wrong with its code.

I want to be able to run `make` and `make test` and compile the other projects that can be compiled like `stack` and `queue` and just show me the compilation error of `cbuffer` but not to stop the `make` process.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to compile with errors? Anyway, you can [call makefiles from other makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206128/how-to-call-makefile-from-another-makefile). so maybe try compiling individualy using makefile and call these makefiles using a master makefile .

Comment: The easiest way would be to call `make -k` which ignores errors and keeps going as much as it can.

Comment: Regarding your projects (such as `stack` and `cbuffer`), how is Make supposed to know how to build those executables, if you don't tell it? And how can we advise you how to explain it to Make, if you don't tell us? (And do you really have a header file (`.h`) for each source file?)

Comment: Did you try to tell make which specific target to make, in example `make stack` or `make stack queue`?